# RadzenDropDown checkbox values to comma separated list

Tags: c#, blazor

I want to create a string with comma when I select each Zone from the multiselect `RadzenDropDown` .

```
 <label>Zone</label>
                <RadzenDropDown class="form-control w-100" placeholder="Select Zone"
                            AllowClear="true"                                FilterCaseSensitivity="FilterCaseSensitivity.CaseInsensitive"
                            FilterOperator="StringFilterOperator.StartsWith"
                            AllowFiltering="true"
                            Multiple="true"
                            @bind-Value="@SelectedValues"
                            TextProperty="Name" ValueProperty="Code" Data="@_ZoneList.Select(x=> new { Name = x.EntityName, Code = x.EntityCode.toString()}).ToList()" Change="@(args => onOrgChange(args, 3))" />
```

I have tried below code:

```
       @code{
    IEnumerable<string> EntityCodes = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
        
        IEnumerable<string> SelectedValues
        {
            get
            {
                return EntityCodes;
            }
            set
            {
                if (EntityCodes != value)
                {
                    EntityCodes = value;               
                }
            }
        }
    
   List<OrgItemDetails> _ZoneList = new List<OrgItemDetails>
            {
                new OrgItemDetails { EntityCode = "100P",EntityName="EntityName1" },
                new OrgItemDetails { EntityCode = "1101",EntityName="EntityName2"},
                new OrgItemDetails { EntityCode = "1234T",EntityName="EntityName3"},
                new OrgItemDetails { EntityCode = "1U11",EntityName="EntityName4"},
                new OrgItemDetails { EntityCode = "66W1",EntityName="EntityName5"}
            };   
    
        public async Task onOrgChange(object args, int priorityId)
        {
        string entityCodes = args+",";
        }
        }
```

I am expecting this output when click each checkbox from the `RadzenDropDown`

```
entityCodes = "100P,1101,66W1,.....";
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the current output is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have refer to the [Radzendropdown mutiple selection demo](https://blazor.radzen.com/dropdown). This one which has multiple selection enabled shows how to select multiple values. Here in the dropwdown checkbox `Change event` we will get the selected the values.

```
public async Task onOrgChange(object value, int priorityId)
    {
string entityCodes = (value is IEnumerable<object> ? string.Join(", ", (IEnumerable<object>)value) : value).Tostring();          
    }
```

Now the `entityCodes` will get `"100P,1101,66W1,....."` values. But we should have to modify the `RadzenDropDown`  in the data binding area also.

```
 <label>Zone</label>
            <RadzenDropDown class="form-control w-100" placeholder="Select Zone"
                        AllowClear="true"                                FilterCaseSensitivity="FilterCaseSensitivity.CaseInsensitive"
                        FilterOperator="StringFilterOperator.StartsWith"
                        AllowFiltering="true"
                        Multiple="true"
                        @bind-Value="@SelectedValues"
                        TextProperty="EntityName" ValueProperty="EntityCode" Data="@_ZoneList" Change="@(args => onOrgChange(args, 3))" />
```

Here I have change the `TextProperty="Name"`  to `TextProperty="EntityName"`  and `ValueProperty="Code"` to `ValueProperty="EntityCode"`. Because if we are using `linq` operation there in `Data=""` section then the selected checkbox will miss the selection.